# Error with /_layouts/assetportalbrowser.aspx

Tags: 2010, error, xslt-list-view-web-part, unsafe-updates, windows

The AssetPortalBrowser.aspx page is throwing an error when rendering list or library content (screenshot and ULS output below).  This happens regardless of the site opened from or the list/library you are trying to view.  I've opened the page, and it is just using the XSLListViewWebPart.

I have not been able to identify what has changed that caused this to stop working.

Any suggestions on how to continue troubleshooting or resolve?

**UI Error message**

`"unable to display this web part"`.

**What I've checked/completed so far**:

1. No Modifications done to the page
2. IIS Reset did not correct this
3. Increased the XslTransformTimeout (This is actually what I expected to fix this).
4. No additional server event log errors
5. No SharePoint updates (running Feb 2012 CU)
6. Ensured it's not a list throttling issue (num. of items appears to not matter in this case, as it wont render with 1, 10, or 100 objects).
7. Other places where the XslListviewWebPart is used appears to work (default library views, content and structure, etc), specifically when viewing the same assets as the users are trying to pull up in asset browser, they all work as expected.

**Screenshot**

[image: AssetPortalBrowser.aspx error]

**Relevant ULS Output**

This is an OOTB asset so not sure how to tackle the Unexpected error shown here in the logs, especially since the XSLListView works from other locations.

```
Unexpected  Detected use of SPRequest for previously closed SPWeb object.  Please close SPWeb objects when you are done with all objects obtained from them, but not before.  Stack trace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_ParentWeb()     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationContext.UpdateSelectedPathWithWeb()     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationContext.InitializeSelectedPathAndTreeValues(NameValueCollection queryString)     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationContext.get_SelectedNodePath()     at ASP._layouts_assetportalbrowser_aspx.CallSetLoc()     at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PerformSelect()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.DataBind()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.EnsureDataBound()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.CreateChildControls()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BaseXsltListWebPart.CreateChildControls()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartMobileAdapter.CreateChildControls()     at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at ASP._layouts_assetportalbrowser_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.SiteURLStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.SiteURLRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.SiteURLRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.SiteURLRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.SiteURLRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
    
High    Error while executing web part: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Load(MethodInfo executeMethod, Byte[] queryData, Type[] earlyBoundTypes)     at Microsoft.Xslt.STransform.GetCompiledTransform()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BaseXsltListWebPart.LoadXslCompiledTransform(WSSXmlUrlResolver someXmlResolver)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.GetXslCompiledTransform()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean bDeferExecuteTransform)
    
Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:http://SiteURL)).    Execution Time=1912.99955720629  

Verbose ____SPRequest Objects=13 
    
Verbose ____SQL Query Count=22 

Verbose ____Execution    Time=1912.99955720629
```

Comment: Very good answer. Uninstall KB2844286, worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uninstall windows update KB2844286.

Over the weekend I had to do this to two servers (much to my annoyance) but it did fix this problem. A server reboot was required.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/cc9a557b-93cd-40d5-965c-e0a2f107624d/unable-to-display-this-web-part-error-message-after-patch-kb2844286

Comment: That was the killer update.

Comment: I'm happy to report that uninstalling this and then rebooting my WFE server did resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a post somewhere in the last few days that tracked this down to two recent hot fixes from Windows Update. Sorry I can't give you more to go on, but that's all I can recall and Bingle isn't giving me any love.

Comment: Thx.  I'll look further into that.