# Error in dialog for file selection

Tags: web-part

Since some days I constantly get a webpart error when trying to reference a file on sharepoint. It tells me that the webpart cannot be displayed along with a correlation ID.

[image]

The error associated to the correlation ID is the following:

> Error while executing web part: System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.      at
>   System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Load(MethodInfo executeMethod,
>   Byte[] queryData, Type[] earlyBoundTypes)      at
>   Microsoft.Xslt.STransform.GetCompiledTransform()      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BaseXsltListWebPart.LoadXslCompiledTransform(WSSXmlUrlResolver
>   someXmlResolver)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.GetXslCompiledTransform()   
>    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean
>   bDeferExecuteTransform)

I tried to restart the sharepoint server but with no effect.

Does anybody know what I could try?

Regards

Comment: This was answered a couple of days ago

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72657/error-with-layouts-assetportalbrowser-aspx/72736#72736

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. It worked by uninstalling the windows update.